# Why is Rails executing action on refresh without clicking the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, action, link-to

I have been trying to find this answer everywhere online without luck, maybe this will help someone else.

I installed a ruby gem called socialization, which works fine.. it allows users to follow/unfollow/like/unlike/mention anything.

the issue I am having is I have made two links (one that follows and one that unfollows) the links work and when clicked the records get added and deleted from the db perfectly BUT when i hit refresh the action happens anyway without me clicking the link.

to be as clear as possible the issue is:

If user is currently followed and I refresh the page the will be unfollowed (without clicking the button).. then when they are unfollowed and I refresh the page they will now be followed again (again without clicking the button)

here is the code:

```
<% if current_user.follows?(@user)%>
   <%= link_to "Unfollow", user_path, :action => current_user.unfollow!(@user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Follow", user_path, :action => current_user.follow!(@user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

I think it has something to do with either: the browser caching the links OR the fact that the link generated is

```
<a href="/users/1" action="#&lt;Follow:0x103ce81d8&gt;" class="btn btn-primary" rel="nofollow">Follow</a>
```

and the action gets executed either way

Edit:

```
Rake routes: 

  users_index GET    /users/index(.:format)            users#index
         dashboard_index GET    /dashboard/index(.:format)        dashboard#index
    dashboard_my_rentals GET    /dashboard/my_rentals(.:format)   dashboard#my_rentals
    dashboard_my_credits GET    /dashboard/my_credits(.:format)   dashboard#my_credits
    dashboard_my_invites GET    /dashboard/my_invites(.:format)   dashboard#my_invites
      dashboard_my_faves GET    /dashboard/my_faves(.:format)     dashboard#my_faves
  dashboard_edit_profile GET    /dashboard/edit_profile(.:format) dashboard#edit_profile
           tsmhome_index GET    /tsmhome/index(.:format)          tsmhome#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)             home#index
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                  users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)              users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)         users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)              users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)              users#destroy
                                /show/:id(.:format)               user#show
                    root        /                                 home#index



user controller

  def index
@users = User.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :json => @users }
end


end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :json => @user }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Problem with ur links action.. Check paths using `rake routes` for `follow` and `unfollow`. If you don't find hot to fix, post your `controller methods` and `routes details`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your link `action` is considered as `attribute` of `link_to tag`. Because `action` should be given as second parameter. Check [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). For get the paths to specific action of controller do `rake routes`. It will list the `routes` and use the same with appending `_path` at end in your `link_to tag`.

I think it may look like below:

```
<% if current_user.follows?(@user)%>
   <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(:user => @user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(:user => @user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

In controller:

```
def follow
  #do something like
  user = User.find(params[:user])
  current_user.follow!(user)
  flash[:success] = "Follwed user #{user.name}"
  redirect_to :back
end

def unfollow
  #do something like
  user = User.find(params[:user])
  current_user.unfollow!(user)
  flash[:success] = "Unfollwed user #{user.name}"
  redirect_to :back
end
```

In routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get 'follow'
    get 'unfollow'
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand! I will try that now.

Comment: what do you have in controller??? where are `follow` and `unfollow` methods define?? are they defined in model??

Comment: the follow and unfollow methods are in the gem is there away for me to generate them so i can edit them?

Comment: ok.. You should to those actions in `controller actions`. Create two actions in controller as I shown in my answer and do there. Where did u post your controller??

Comment: I posted it in the post if you scroll down on the routes code. I am trying your response now.. thanks so much!!!

Comment: I get the erro: Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: Change to `<%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(:user => @user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>` and `<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(:user => @user), :class => "btn btn-primary"%>`